# Scheme quick-sort with filter

Tags: sorting, recursion, scheme, racket, quicksort

I need to write the function (quick-sort pred lst)
**lst** is the list of numbers to be sorted
**pred** is the predicate by which the list is ordered, the signature of this predicate is: **(lambda (x y) …)**

```
- (quick-sort < lst) will sort ascending (small to large)
- (quick-sort > lst) will sort descending (large to small)
- (quick-sort (lambda (x y) (< (car x) (car y))) lst) will sort a list
with inner lists according to the first element of the inner list, ascending.
```

I started with regular quick-sort:

```
(define (quick-sort lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst)        '())
    ((= (length lst) 1) lst)
    (else               (append (quick-sort (filter (lambda (n) (< n (car lst))) lst))
                                (list (car lst))
                                (quick-sort (filter (lambda (n) (> n (car lst))) lst))))))
```

And now I'm trying to do this with pred:

```
(define (quick-sort pred lst)
  (define (quick-sort-help lst)
    (cond   ((null? lst) ())
        ((= (length lst) 1) lst)
        (else 
            (append (quick-sort-help (filter (lambda (n) (pred n (car lst))) lst))
                (list (car lst))
                (quick-sort-help (filter (lambda (n) (not(pred n (car lst)))) lst)))))) (quick-sort-help lst))
```

And I get an infinite recursion or something.

Can you help me solve this problem please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of you don't need the helper function `quick-sort-help`.

---

It recurs infinitely because you apply your helper function to `lst` instead `cdr lst`. In your regular quicksort you have `(filter (lambda (n) (< n (car lst)))` and `(filter (lambda (n) (> n (car lst)))`. But then in the one with the predicate you have the problem that `(not (pred ...)` would cover the cases for `<=` and not `<` if the predicate is `>` and vice versa. So it gets stuck because the first element in the list is always equal with itself.

Here a correct quicksort:

```
(define (qsort f lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      null
      (let ([pivot (car lst)])
        (append (qsort f (filter (λ (n) (f n pivot)) (cdr lst)))
                (list pivot)
                (qsort f (filter (λ (n) (not (f n pivot))) (cdr lst)))))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But when I'm trying to use it with: (qsort (lambda (x y) (< (car x) (car y))) lst) it doesn't work... Any idea why? (it suppose to sort a list
with inner lists according to the first element of the inner list, ascending.

Comment: It doesn't work if an inner list is empty, but `(qsort (lambda (x y) (< (car x) (car y))) '((7 2) (3 6) (5 3)))` produces `(list (list 3 6) (list 5 3) (list 7 2))`. Isn't that what you want?